# Pass PHP fetch variable to another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that submits to firstpage.php, this page includes the code to insert all form values into the database and check for duplicate entries, if the entry is a duplicate , display the duplicate entry using the following php code

```
 $checkstudentID = mysqli_query
($dbcon, "SELECT studentid from courses WHERE studentid = '$studentid'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($checkstudentID) > 0){
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbcon, "SELECT ckb from courses WHERE studentid = ?")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$studentid); 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $ckb);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

        printf("<br /><center><h1>Your Student ID is</h1> <h2>%s.</h2><h1> Subjects Registered :  %s\n </h1>", $studentid, $ckb );

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($dbcon);


        die("  <p> The Student ID  <strong>$studentid </strong>already exists. <a href=\"update.html\">Update</a></p>");
```

the page update.html includes an update form that submits to update.php

how can I pass the the single fetched row variable (subjects registered/$ckb) to update.html ?

I tried the following so far:

at the firstpage.php I started a session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['subjects'] = '$ckb';
```

and at the update.html > renamed to update2.php and added the following at the top of the page

```
 <?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['sujects'];
?>
```

and at the input field the `value="<?php echo $ckb;?>"`

What am I missing ?

Please note, that the variable I want to pass is the subjects registered related to the student id checked in firstpage.php file meaning this :

```
printf("<br /><center><h1>Your Student ID is</h1> <h2>%s.</h2><h1> Subjects Registered :  **%s**\n </h1>", $studentid, $ckb );
```

but its either completely wrong or I'm just passing the wrong variable

Comment: Don't use `$_SESSION['subjects'] = '$ckb';` - the single quotes around the variable will give you the literal string `$ckb`, rather than the value of the variable. Remove the single quotes there and see what happens. You'll also need to set `$ckb` again in your second page, if you're trying to echo its value.

Comment: maybe your problem is `'$ckb'` remove the singlle quotes

Comment: `subjects` in one place `sujects` in another

Comment: Fixed both "syntaxes" , however nothing is being passed or echoed to update2.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my question I found an easy and effective by passing the variables through the url.

Meaning...

In my firstpage.php, the href links to my update2.php page became as follows:

```
<a href=\"update2.php?studentid=$studentid&ckb=$cc\">Update</a>
```

The $studentid and $cc variables are previously defined in my code where I "get" them from the input fields of the form.

In update2.php, the page which I would like to pass the variables to I inserted the following code

```
<?php
$studentid= $_GET['studentid'];
$cc = $_GET['ckb'];
?>
```

Which allowed me to use the variables throughout the rest of the php code, where for my case I wanted them to be the "values" of a new form input field, as shown below :

```
<input name="newcourses" type="text" id="newcourses" maxlength="70" value="<?php echo $cc?>"" />
```

I recommend anyone who wants a more clear idea and read more about other methods to pass variables across php pages to check [this](http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=Php_passing_variables.php) out >> [Pass PHP fetch variable...](http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=Php_passing_variables.php)

Answer (score 1):

Remove quotes in:

```
$_SESSION['subjects'] = '$ckb';
```

So it will be:

```
$_SESSION['subjects'] = $ckb;
```

And update 2nd file to this:

```
 <?php
session_start();
$ckb = $_SESSION['subjects'];
?>
....
<input type='text' value="<?php echo $ckb;?>" />
```

Note: also, you wrote `sujects` in second file, its ok in my code example.

Comment: I think it's not answer. because is output `$ckb` (string). but the problem about output is empty.

Comment: It can't output `$ckb` as string just because `$ckb` variable is not defined in second file. I noticed 2 mistakes: quotes around variable in 1st file and missing assigning to `$ckb` in 2nd. Or question is incorrect. I'd answered the question.

Comment: he say `echo $_SESSION['sujects'];` not working. not `echo $ckb`

Comment: I tried with another  $_SESSION['subjects'] = $studentid
and tried to echo that, its passing nothing...

Comment: @Azizi, can you please update your answer so we can see your code after update. Show how exactly you assign variables in first file and in second file and how you output them in second file.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav , I posted my answer below, thank you for following up with this ..